# How to avoid going into cache block in c# and return to loop iteration?

Tags: c#, for-loop

Here is my code

```
     public List<Union100> Get(String IdType)
     {
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                var typeIdOfObjectType = db.Objects.Where(x => x.ObjectsName == 
                        ObjectTypeName).Select(x => x.ObjectTgId).First();
                var d = GetParent();
            }
        }
        catch (exception e)
        {
        }
     }
```

suppose I get null in `typeIdOfObjectType` variable in 1st iteration so it should return to for loop instead of going to cache block 
 it should continue  with `i = 2` iteration 
what can I do for this ?

Comment: by moving `try` into iteration scope? ... but better would be not causing an exception at the first place ... obviously using `First()` is the problem ... it will not return `null` for empty IEnumerable

Comment: You know `continue` is an actual statement, right? (Also, that `.First()` probably needs to be `.FirstOrDefault()`, otherwise you're just going to get an exception if no results come from the `Select` -- an exception that you should be avoiding, not catching.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line where you do the query, there are several calls, some of which depend on the calls before them to return something. If any of these return `null`, then an exception will be thrown.

Using the null propagation syntax can help you avoid this:

```
for (var i = 0;i <= 3; i++)
{
    var typeIdOfObjectType = 
                    db? // If db is null, then typeIdOfObjectType will be null
                      .Objects? // The same if .Objects is null
                      .Where(x => x.ObjectsName == ObjectTypeName)
                      .Select(x => x.ObjectTgId)
                      .First();

    if(typeIdOfObjectType == null)
    {
        continue; // Jump to the next iteration
    }

    // (Anything below here will be skipped for any iteration
    // where typeIdOfObjectType was null) 
}
```

This will check the value of `db`, and of `db.Objects` before calling `Where(..)` and the rest, and if either of these are `NULL`, then that will be set as the value of your variable, and you may avoid some exceptions.

Another source of null-ref. exceptions may be if the `Where(..)`clause does not find anything; if so, the `.First()` call will throw an exception. You should therefore replace it with a `FirstOrDefault()`, which will return `null` instead.

Finally, I'd add a check to see if `typeIdOfObjectType` is `null`, and if so, call `continue`, which skips whatever logic remains in the loop, and jumps to the nest iteration instead.

Answer (score 2):

Replace "First()" to FirstOrDefault() and the code will return NULL and not throw a exception.

Here:

```
var `typeIdOfObjectType` = 
        db.Objects
            .Where(x => x.ObjectsName == ObjectTypeName)
            .Select(x => x.ObjectTgId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use `FirstOrDefault();`  instead of `First();`

Then, you could use a `try/catch` inside the block. By doing these, your loop will not stop if you have an exception.

Ex:

```
 public List<Union100> Get(String IdType)
 {
     for (var i = 0;i <= 3; i++)
     {
         try
         {
             var typeIdOfObjectType = db.Objects.Where(x => x.ObjectsName == ObjectTypeName).Select(x => x.ObjectTgId).FirstOrDefault();
             var d = GetParent();
         }
         catch{}
     }
 }
```